# Decimal format from data base and local

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

Can someone explain me why is that so:

```
public static string ToValueString(this decimal value)
{
    return value.ToString(EnUsCulture);
}
```

When I call it like this:

```
var result = 1M.ToValueString();
```

I got result:

```
"1"
```

Now a strange situation to come. I have decimal values that I get from database. Values are ***decimal(18,4)***. I have value from db for example ***1***. I can see it in debugger like ***1***, not ***1.0000***. But when I call:

```
var result = value.ToValueString();//where value == 1
```

I got result:

```
"1.0000"
```

Why is that so? Why in first variant decimal ***1*** return ***"1"*** and ***"1.0000"*** in second variant

Comment: Sadly, `decimal` "remembers" decimal places, even if they're all zeros. Observe: `var x = 1m; Console.WriteLine(x); x /= 100; Console.WriteLine(x); x *= 100; Console.WriteLine(x);` So it's best to use the `ToString` overload and give it a specific format string.

Comment: @Corak: this should be an answer.